# How to replace mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db') with variable?

Tags: php

I am having trouble doing this:

```
$database = '"localhost","my_user","my_password","mydb"';
mysqli = new mysqli($database);
```

Comment: Check this link  it gives you a detailed explanation https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 1):

Each argument needs to be its own variable, like this:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'mydb';
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$server ="localhost";
$user_server ="my_user";
$password   ="my_password";
$database   = "mydb";

$conn = new mysqli($server,$user_server,$password,$database);

if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Failed to connect".$conn->connect_error);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[OOP style](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)** takes four parameters (with an optional socket as well):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

So you could split them out as such:

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'my_user';
$password = 'my_password';
$database = 'my_db';

$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $username, $password, $database);
```

Or do a procedural approach with the same variables:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all define database connection with `variable`

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'logintest';
$pass = 'logintest';
$db = 'vibo';
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if($mysqli->connect_error) 
 die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

return $mysqli;
```